# A word describing physical or online address

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm working on an application that tracks accredited activities doctors can participate in and gain credits. These can be seminars, online courses etc. What should I call the field whose value can be either a physical address (i.e. the address of a hotel) or a URL?

Could 'venue' be used when referring to a URL of an online course?

Comment: The value of the field is either a web address or a physical address...aren't those both "addresses"?

Comment: @Juhasz Is it something people would say? For example, calling the field "address" in the Czech language would be technically correct. However, no one would use it in that way.

Comment: Do you mean, would someone say, "The seminar's address is www.online_seminar.com"? They probably would not.  But if you're naming a field on a form or a table, "address" seems fine.

Comment: Is this for labeling the actual field on a form that a human has to fill out, or is this for labeling a field in your SQL database? In the former case, simply label it "street address or URL". In the latter case, you can label it absolutely anything you want (and incidentally this question is off-topic for much the same reason).

Comment: @RegDwigнt it's for a label people will read. How comes the question would be off-topic if it was for a database field? It's important to use accurate naming.

Comment: If it is for people to read, understand and then use, forget pedantic exactitude. Even if there were a single word that encompasses street address and URL, hardly any user of the form would know it. Say what you mean in the plainest language possible.

Comment: @pikausp If you need to use a word for something that might be a physical address or a URL then "address" is as good as anything. If you are just naming a table then describe it in the name - "AddressOrUrl".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Naming, including naming programming variables/classes is off-topic as mentioned in the help centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Location**.

> a place where something happens or exists; the position of something

[Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/location)

> A Uniform Resource Locator (URL), colloquially termed a web address, is a reference to a web resource that specifies its *location* (emphasis added)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)

The term location is well known both in the sense of a web address, and a physical place.